# Is a method thread-safe if the return value is declared/returned outside of a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized-block

```
public Foo getFoo(){
    Foo foo = null;

    synchronized(fooList){
        if(fooList.size() > 0){
            foo = fooList.remove(0);
        }
    }

    return foo;
}
```

Since `foo` is declared outside of the synchronized block, does the potential exist of returning bad data?

Comment: it's ok this way, but the example as you gave it doesn't motivate the existence of `foo`. Just saying  `return  fooList.remove(0)` is not acceptable in your context?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, It's legacy code. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each thread instance calling `getFoo()` will have its own `foo` instance. Thus `foo` is thread safe and doesn't need synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

What does "bad data" mean in this context? `fooList` may change asynchronously before `synchronized(fooList)` and after the corresponding closing brace, before `return foo;` (more generally speaking, up to the moment the returned value is used.) What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: If this method returns `null`, then the logic is that the `fooList` is empty. I want to make sure that this method doesn't return `null` when `fooList` is not empty.

Comment: OK I get the point. If at the moment of locking the monitor for `fooList` it is not empty (and ALL accesses to `fooList` are synchronized on it!) then you will never get `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`getFoo` will not return stale data, since `Foo foo` is local variable AND `fooList` is synchronized

Local variable is thread safe since each thread call will create a new `Foo` object, instead of sharing single object. While instead variable is not thread safe, since multiple threads can access `fooList`, but in this case the `fooList` is already synchronized.